# Error in plot.nn(company_model, rep = "best") : weights were not calculated

Tags: r

Error in plot.nn(company_model, rep = "best") : weights were not calculated. How to calculate them?

[image: enter image description hereee]

Comment: can  you share an example of the dataset? I don't get this issue if i do it with example datasets

Comment: yes!absolutely.

Comment: i have shared a snap of my data ,if you also need code just let me know